# why the character in shell is still chinese?

Tags: vim

my system is xp+gvim,i have set language in  registry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe]

"CodePage"=dword: 437
```

my cmd information is english now,and my gvim is is english too ,in my _vimrc

```
set langmenu=en_US 
let $LANG = "en_US"
```

when i input `:!date` in command mode of gvim ,the ouput is chinese,how can i make it into english?

[image]

when i input in cmd command ,i got :
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\sanya>date
The current date is: ??? 2014-01-11
Enter the new date: (yy-mm-dd)

why :!chcp from inside Vim   i get 936 ,not 437?

Comment: If you type `date` in a shell (without involving vim, what is the output then?

Comment: What's the output of `:!chcp` from inside Vim?!

Comment: Just an idea: would it help to define a similar `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%ProgramFiles%_Vim_vim74_vimrun.exe` registry key?!

Comment: there is no %ProgramFiles%_Vim_vim74_vimrun.exe  in my registry key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vim settings don't affect any external commands launched from it (at least pure Windows applications don't consider `$LANG`, which is a Unix concept).

The *codepage* just influences the characters that can be displayed (and input) in the console; I don't think it changes the user's language. To do that, you have to use Control Panel > Regional Settings, or use a programmatic alternative (like here: [how to change system locale in windows 2003 using command line](https://serverfault.com/questions/146730/how-to-change-system-locale-in-windows-2003-using-command-line)).